# Difference between 구경하다 and 구하다 : Look Around

Tags: vocabulary, translation, meaning, word-usage

What is the word difference between these two words: 구경하다 and 구하다 ?
Do they both mean look around?

Comment: 구경하다 means "to look around, to sightsee". 구하다 just means to "save (people in danger)" or to "find (something you need)"

Comment: What dictionary are you using to look up words? 구하다 shouldn't be "look around" in any dictionary.

Comment: you are asking a lot of dictionary search type of questions and almost all of them are being flagged as low quality. Please add more details or context to your questions. Why do you think 구경하다 and 구하다 mean the same or similar thing? Please link to any resources that gave this idea